# Does the fact that there are more webdesign compared to usability tags suggest that we need to support Area 51 Web Design?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the Area 51 Web Design [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647/web-design) and the questions with tags for web design on this website and StackOverflow, does it make sense for people here to also commit to the Web Design proposal and make this place more focused on pure UX issues? I would definitely like to see more usability and user experience tags compared to web design tags.

And by supporting Area 51 Web Design I don't mean that questions relevant to UX should be posted there as well, just that we need to try and move as much of the specific web design questions off UX StackExchange so we can focus more on the problem solving side of things, as JonW indicated. Or perhaps make a clear distinction with the Graphic Design people about what kind of questions go where.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really clear what the web design proposal is for. Most of the sample questions are about "What is the best tool to do X". However, trawling through all the example ones it *looks* to be a site to take some of the strain off Stack Overflow - a place for web design implementation questions.

If that is the case then people are free to go and commit to that site, but that's not going to change *this* site. If questions come in to UX.SE about implementing web design then they'll be closed as off topic or possibly migrated elsewhere. That's not going to change just because there might be a new migration target. Implementation questions are off topic, but UX questions aren't.

Also, even if there is a site dedicated to web design implementation questions that's not going to *increase* the Usability or UX type tags on this site. All it'll do is (possibly) reduce the number of questions and visitors to this site.

User Experience is about *what* the solution to a problem should be, whereas StackOverflow (and potentially this new Web Design site) will be about *how* to do it. If people are interested in the implementation side of things then sure, go and commit to that.

Answer (score 0):

'Web design' seems like a rather redundant tag for this site, in that likely 80%(?) of the UX questions here pertain to Web Design.

That doesn't mean we don't support Web Design. But it should be noted that we already have a LOT of overlap with all the sites on the SE network.

All of these sites pertain to web design:

- stackoverflow
- UX
- graphicdesign
- webmasters

And I'm sure there are others I'm not even aware of.

If anything, I think 'Web Design' should be merged with 'graphic design'.

Comment: I think so too, but there are also a lot of niche topics in graphic design that the typical web designer probably doesn't worry too much about. The problem is that web design is almost as much about front-end development as it is design, so there is a lot of overlap which is also the case for UX design.